# "Like" button not exhibiting expected behavior

Tags: html, facebook-like

Short version:  In test app with test users, the newly-implemented "Like" button won't turn grey and is immediately clickable again.  Am I using the "Like" button incorrectly so that it exhibits this behavior?

I've implemented Facebook's "Like" button on a Facebook Application I've been a part of designing and, while the button is there, clickable, and reports that test users Like the app, the button won't turn grey and is clickable again.  Now the app itself is currently in sandbox mode, and we're testing the app with nothing but test users.  The og tags and the iframe code for the "Like" button are contained in the html for the canvas page.  The og tags read as:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="GameName Dev" />
<meta property="og:type" content="game" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://apps.facebook.com/gamenamedev/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://image.on/server.jpg" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="GameName Dev" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="MY_APP_ID" />
```

Thank you for any help you may be able to give.

Answer (score 2):

If the app is in sandbox mode that URL is not reachable by Facebook's crawler because it operates in a logged-out context and won't work properly because the app is 'invisible' - take the app out of sandbox, run the URL through [Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to clear the cache and pick up the meta tags and it should be OK

As an aside, I don't really understand why you're pointing a Like button at the app's canvas URL, nobody liking that URL will be contactable by you, nor will you be able to obtain statistics about them - surely creating a Page for the app would be better?